# Can not create object in Django views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm

I'd like to create objects in a views, but can not figure out why I get `500` error instead.

Here is the relevant code:

```
lvt = LastVisitedTopic.objects.create(user=uid, topic=t.id, lastvisited=lv)
```

And the model is:

```
class LastVisitedTopic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    lastvisited = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
    managed = True     
    app_label = 'myforum'
```

The parameters passed to the create method seem to be ok:

```
print 'uid, t.id, lv \n', uid, t.id, lv
```

Yields:

```
    uid, t.id, lv 
1 202798 2014-10-19 03:10:00+00:00
```

I'm stock on this for a while so really appreciate your clues.

**UPDATE:** 
here is the whole views, in case it can help:

```
def notify_ajax(request):
    #if request.method == 'GET':
        args = {}
        alerts = []
        mt_alerts = []
        uid = request.user.id
        numalerts = 0

        if Topic.objects.filter(Q(post__creator_id=uid) | Q(creator_id=uid)).exists():
            mypartopics = Topic.objects.filter(Q(post__creator_id=uid) | Q(creator_id=uid)).distinct().order_by("-created")
            for t in mypartopics:
                print t.title
                #Check whether there is record of the topic in LastVisitedTopic
                if not LastVisitedTopic.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id, user_id=uid).exists():
                    print 'LastVisitedTopic not exists so to be created...'
                    #Calculate the record
                    #If topic has posts by this user
                    if Post.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id, creator_id=uid).exists():
                        print 'this topic has posts...\n'
                    #Last post time by this user is assumed as the last time he visited the topic
                        last_post = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id, creator_id=uid).latest('created')
                        print 'latest post found'
                        lv = last_post.created
                        print 'lv to be added from post', lv
                        print 'uid, t.id, lv \n', uid, t.id, lv
                        lvt = LastVisitedTopic.objects.create(user=uid, topic=t.id, lastvisited=lv)
                        print 'last visit record created'                   
                    #Else last visit is assumed as the time when the topic is created
                    else:
                        lv = t.created
                        print 'lv added from topic'


                        lvt = LastVisitedTopic.objects.create(user=uid,topic=t.id, lastvisited='%s')


                        print 'last visit record created equal to topic creation time'                  



                else:
                    print 'record for this topic exists', 
                    track = LastVisitedTopic.objects.get(topic_id=t.id, user_id=uid)
                    print 'last visited at', track.lastvisited

                #Check whether the topic lastposted field is not empty, if so, fill it
                if not t.lastposted:
                    if Post.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id).exists():
                        topic_lp= Post.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id).latest('created')
                        t.lastposted = topic_lp.created
                        t.save()
                        print 'new t.lastposted saved'
                    else:
                        t.lastposted = t.created
                        t.save()
                else:
                    print 't.lastposted for this topic exists', t.lastposted




                #Now compare last visit by the user with last topic post
                try:
                    print '\n\n\nnow trying...'
                    track = LastVisitedTopic.objects.get(topic_id=t.id, user_id=uid)
                    print 'track', track.id
                    last_visit = track.lastvisited
                    print 'last visit', last_visit
                    print 't.lastposted', t.lastposted

                    if t.lastposted > last_visit :
                        print 'topic posted after the last visit'
                        #last_posts = Post.objects.filter(topic_id=t.id).latest()
                        #if last_post.created >= last_visit:
                        alerts.append({'title':t.title, 'slug':t.slug}) 
                    else:
                        print 'lastposted before last visit'
                except:
                    print 't excpeton'
                    pass

            print 'alerts', alerts
            print 'alerst length', len(alerts)
            args['alerts'] = alerts
            return render(request, '_alerts.html', args)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Have you tried to do the same in dev server and debug it?

Comment: I get just a 500: `[02/Mar/2016 14:43:56]"GET /notify HTTP/1.1" 500 14683`. I am on dev server. and request is an ajax request.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings?

Comment: Yes, I do have `DEBUG = True`

Comment: Thats strange. Add `import pdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in your views and debug the issue. Find out what the problem is. Only then someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I put `import pdb; ipdb.set_trace()` before and after the create line. Nothing other than the same old `500` error printed out in the console.

Comment: If this is an Ajax request, you can see the full response in the browser's dev tools; you should get the full error page there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added the views. The only thing that I get in my browser console is this: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/notify 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Comment: The tools can give you much more information than that. In Chrome for example, you have the Network tab, which shows all requests. Your Ajax request will show up there; click on it, you will see the response that was received from the server. That will also have a Preview sub-tab to see the rendered response, which will be the full Django debug page.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I get this error in the chrome console: `Cannot assign "1L": "LastVisitedTopic.user" must be a "User" instance.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you need an actual User, not an ID. You could just pass `request.user` directly. You'll probably get the same error for topic; again, you should just pass the object itself.

```
LastVisitedTopic.objects.create(user=request.user, topic=t, lastvisited=lv)
```